# Junit Testing with Play framework

Tags: java, junit, playframework-2.0

am using Play 2 framework with Java. I have some methods that manipulate global Json object in the class and the result is placed in an array. Which means that the methods do not take in variables and return void. Can someone explain to me how to use the junit test to test these methods.  I am aware of testing methods that take in variables and explicitly return values when testing with junit.

thank you.

Answer (score 2):

To make your method testable, you'll need to change it so it takes the JSON object and return another one.

Instead of doing:

```
myMethod();
```

You'll do:

```
myModifiedJsonObject = myMethod(myJsonObject);
```

And *global* stuff is bad.